# Autoclose brackets and quotes in IPython

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to autoclose brackets and quotes in IPython.
Just like in RStudio when you type an opening bracket like [ it automatically types the closing bracket ] and moves the cursor inside the brackets. Same thing with quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Possible, probably not too hard, but not trivial. Might need to update the underlying library (in progress), and to dig in CodeMirror doc to see if there is already such an option. If you are interested in diving in the code/submit Patch I would suggest asking for directions on the ML / on github.